# WPF Error - "Provide value on 'system.windows.baml2006.typeconvertermarkupextension' threw an exception."

Tags: wpf, templates, data-binding

I added DataGrid columns because I wanted to customize them by myself like column width etc, and after that I started to receiving that popup message. When I remove data under `<DataGrid.Columns>` everything is fine, I don't know why this is happening. I am very new to WPF and I can not spot error.

```
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,128,10,0" Background="Transparent">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}" Header="Product Name"    MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15px" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"     Header="Quantity"       MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15px" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=NumberOfOrder}" Header="Order Number"  MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15px" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerName}"  Header="Customer"      Width="*"       FontSize="15px" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I suspect width=="*" is the issue, please check by removing that Width="*", set some value to that width.

Comment: Nope, it's not about that. The width of * sized columns is calculated by allocating space for the auto, and fixed width columns, and then dividing up the remaining space. So if there's only one * sized column, it will get all the remaining space, that's why I am using "*" and the end. (like my last column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FontSize` is a `double`, so the 'px' is throwing the error.
Try changing the `FontSize` to just '15'

i.e.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}" Header="Product Name"    MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"     Header="Quantity"       MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=NumberOfOrder}" Header="Order Number"  MinWidth="30"   FontSize="15" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerName}"  Header="Customer"      Width="*"       FontSize="15" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Yes dude, that is true! it works now, but I saw somewhere someone used px and I saw it worked, here is the code I saw before and this confused me now.. `<Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="50"  FontSize="15px" />` Can you explain it a little bit, how come px works for this guy?

Comment: As it's a custom `DataGridTextColumn` he may have overridden the `FontSize` property (Not sure if this is possible, just a guess). Other than that it shouldn't work